# How to do this sql request

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

i'm not really good in SQL, i want to insert 2 values retrived by a php form, and a 3dr value from another table:

```
insert into tab1(A,B,C) values('foo,'bar',select id from tab2 where name = "Doe")
```

I've been on mysql doc, it says it's possible to do that, but there is  no exemple...

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: use have missed up the ' in foo use 'foo' like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax here.

I could be like:

```
INSERT INTO tab1(A,B,C) 
SELECT 'foo','bar', id from tab2 where name = "Doe"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `INSERT INTO SELECT`, so query will be like this:

```
 INSERT INTO tab1(A,B,C) 
 SELECT 'foo', 'bar', `id` FROM tab2 where name = 'Doe'
```

More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO tab1(A,B,C)
SELECT 'foo', 'bar', id FROM tab2 where name = 'Doe';
```

This will create table like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|    foo    |     bar     |           id          |
---------------------------------------------------
|    foo    |     bar     |     id1 from tab2     |
|    foo    |     bar     |     id2 from tab2     |
|    foo    |     bar     |     id3 from tab2     |
|    foo    |     bar     |     id4 from tab2     |
|    foo    |     bar     |     id5 from tab2     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

This data will be inserted into tab2.